# Python34: Using Dictionary Comprehension to Copy Values form one list of dictionaries to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.4, dictionary-comprehension

I am writing a script to process data so I have a list containing dictionaries with calculated values. Once I calculate new ones I want to append the appropriate dictionary with new entries.

I know I could do this with list or np array, but I want to learn how to use dictionaries. I also just started using list comprehension so I want to get a better understanding on how to use it appropriately. So making life hard on myself.

Here is simplified examples.

I calculate values and place them in the dictionary, which then goes in a list to correspond for each entry.

```
A=[{'low':1},{'low':2}]
print(A)
[{'low': 1}, {'low': 2}]   # entry 0 corresponds to sample 1 and the next to sample 2

B=[{'hi':1},{'hi':2}]
print(B)
[{'hi': 1}, {'hi': 2}]   # entry 0 corresponds to sample 1 and the next to sample 2

C=[{}]*len(A)   # initialize list to contain a dictionary for each sample. Each dictionary will receive the corresponding values copied from A and B
print(C)
[{}, {}]
```

Now I try to use dictionary comprehensions

```
{C[x].update(A[x]) for x in range(len(A))}
print(C)
[{'low': 2}, {'low': 2}]
```

The results is not what I expected. I want something like this:

```
[{'low':1,'high':1},{'low':1,'high':1}]
```

What am I not understanding here...

Thanks

Comment: That's a set comprehension.

Comment: Are you expecting all values to be 1, not 1 or 2?

Comment: On the grounds of complex is better than complicated, I would encourage using loops here, dictionary comprehension is rarely clear.

Comment: If you »want to append the appropriate dictionary with new entries«, why don't you just use `.append()` on the list to append a new dictionary?

Comment: You aren't using `B` at all when updating `C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term `C=[{}]*len(A)` creates a list of `len(A)` entries which all are the same dictionary.  Changes to `C[0]` will also change `C[1]` because the two are identical.

Use `C = [ {} for _ in A ]` to create a new dictionary as each element of the list.

But all in all, as I mentioned in the comment above, I would consider appending the new dictionaries to an existing list; that sounds most like what you originally intended.

Comment: Thank you, the created the result I was originally expecting.

Comment: The `_` is just a variable (you could also use `x` or whatever).  Using `_` just is a convention for a dummy variable which is needed syntactically but which isn't used.  If you use a normally named variable and then do not use it, typical IDEs like PyDev might give a warning for it for an unused variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `A` and `B` together to update `C`. Here's one possible solution.

```
A=[{'low':1},{'low':2}]
B=[{'hi':1},{'hi':2}]

C = [dict(a.items() + b.items()) for a,b in zip(A, B)]
```